# how to fix invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can I fix my error of indexes on my json through foreach? by the way this is my json  1.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "sección":"Inventario",
      "data":[  
         {  
            "id":"11",
            "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/items.png",
            "value":"Productos",
            "seccion_id":"1",
            "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/inventario\/product"
         },
         {  
            "id":"14",
            "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/employees.png",
            "value":"Provedores",
            "seccion_id":"1",
            "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/provedor\/provedor"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "sección":"Compras",
      "data":[  
         {  
            "id":"22",
            "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/suppliers.png",
            "value":"Compras",
            "seccion_id":"2",
            "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/compras\/compras"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I would like to know how can I Access my indexes to foreach and do it properly. because im getting  invalid argument supplied for foreach()

controller

```
public function getModules($id_module) {
    if ($this->session->userdata('log')) {
        $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
        $menu = array();
        $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
        foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion){
            $modules = $this->module->query("SELECT CONCAT('".$seccion['id']."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id,CONCAT('".base_url('assets/img/sidebar')."','/',storelte_modulo.icon) as icon, storelte_modulo.modulo AS value,storelte_modulo.seccion_id,CONCAT('".base_url()."',storelte_modulo.url) AS  url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON  storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id = $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.STATUS = 1");
            $seccions[$index]['data'] = $modules;
            if (!count($seccions[$index]['data'])) {
                unset($seccions[$index]);
            }
        }
        foreach ($seccions as $item) {
            array_push($menu,$item);
        }

        $this->json($menu);
    }
```

model

```
 public function get_rows() {
     $this->db->select('id,seccion');
     $this->db->from('storelte_seccion');

     return $this
         ->db
         ->get()
         ->result_array()
     ;
 }

 public function query($query){
     return $this
         ->db
         ->query($query)
         ->result_array()
     ;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<h3 class="text-center">Welcome to storeLTE, click a module below to get started!</h3>
<div class="home_module_list">
    <div class="module_item">
        <?php foreach ($seccions as $session) { ?>
          <div class="module_item" title="<?= $session['value'];?>">
            <a href="<?= $session['url']; ?>"><img src="<?= $session['icon']; ?>"/></a>
            <a href="<?= $session['url']; ?>"><?= $session['value']?></a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make it easier for us by showing the script that actually runs. You just show some function definitions but no execute instructions.  Do you call these functions? where? with which argument? and how does the JSON fit into all of this?  You mentioned a problem with `foreach` but there are a couple of `foreach` loops in your code so which are you referring to? make it easy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem because `$session` in `foreach ($seccions as $session)` it is list, but not assoc array. You must use one more `foreach` for each element inside `data`. Here example:

```
$json = '[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "sección":"Inventario",
      "data":[  
         {  
            "id":"11",
            "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/items.png",
            "value":"Productos",
            "seccion_id":"1",
            "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/inventario\/product"
         },
         {  
            "id":"14",
            "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/employees.png",
            "value":"Provedores",
            "seccion_id":"1",
            "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/provedor\/provedor"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "sección":"Compras",
      "data":[  
         {  
            "id":"22",
            "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/suppliers.png",
            "value":"Compras",
            "seccion_id":"2",
            "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/compras\/compras"
         }
      ]
   }
]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($seccions as $section) {
    echo 'id = ' . $section['id'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'sección = ' . $section['sección'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Data of sección:<br/>';
    // each array inside data - $seccions[0]['data'][0], $seccions[0]['data'][1] etc.
    foreach ($section['data'] as $dataItem) {
        echo 'data id = ' . $dataItem['id'] . '<br/>';
        echo 'data icon = ' . $dataItem['icon'] . '<br/>';
        echo 'data value = ' . $dataItem['value'] . '<br/>';
        echo 'data seccion_id = ' . $dataItem['seccion_id'] . '<br/>';
        echo 'data url = ' . $dataItem['url'] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Here example with your html:

```
<div class="module_item">
    <?php foreach ($array as $session) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($session['data'] as $itemData) : ?>
            <div class="module_item" title="<?= $itemData['value'] ?>">
                <a href="<?= $itemData['url'] ?>"><img src="<?= $itemData['icon'] ?>"/></a>
                <a href="<?= $itemData['url'] ?>"><?= $itemData['value']?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: how can I do it with my code example? I didnt understand the first one. I would like to do it with the json